# MySql PHP connect to a mysql database on different server not working

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a host on `godaddy` and different domain name on it and i have a mysql database on it.

I have a database on server A and i have a website on a serve B.

I want to connect the website on server B with the database on server A.

First i have create a Remote MySQL and i added the ip  for the access host
then i have create a new user for my database then i add this user to mydatabase

Then i use this code to connect to the database

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$database);
define('DB_SERVER', 'www.eiwms-progroup.com'); //name of the server that contain the database 
define('DB_USERNAME', 'ts*****');//the user that i created 
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'm********'); //the password of this user
define('DB_DATABASE', 'ts******');  //database Name
$conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
// Check connection
if ($conn)
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }else{
    echo"Connect";
}
```

I have upload the file that contain the code to the server B the domain name on this server is ts-lb.com

I have receive this message **Failed to connect to MySQL:** without any other error

i have tried to add that to my code

```
define('DB_SERVER', 'www.eiwms-progroup.com:3306'); //name of the server that contain the database
```

But also i have the same error message nothing change

Also i tried to put the domain name (ts-lb.com) on the Remote MySQL

But also i have receive the same message

**Any one can help to solve my problem on How to connect to a database on different server??!**!

Comment: Check that the connection is made BEFORE running `$conn->set_charset("utf8");` Afterall if the connection fails, there is no point running that line of code anyway

Comment: I think you should [enable the remote connection](https://www.godaddy.com/help/connect-to-databases-remotely-16103)

Comment: @Mohammad i have did it before In the Host field, i enter the IP address from where i want to access my databases.

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have erase $conn->set_charset("utf8"); but i have same message is my code to connect is correct ??!!

Comment: You seem to be connection twice, once on line 1 and again on line 6. Both are using the same variable to hold the connection handle i.e. `$conn`

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have erase the first line and also i have the same message

Comment: Did you do as @Mohammad suggested yet?

Comment: When I try and connect with a bogus userid and password, I get a `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'fred'@'mydomain' (using password: YES)` So i would say you have activated remote login. But that means you shoudl be getting a sensible error message also

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes i did and now i change my code $servername = "www.eiwms-progroup.com";
$username = "t****";
$password = "m*****";
$db="t*****";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$db);

// Check connection
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully"; and it work now thx for your time